'SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED' was not declared in this scope
I can't flash esp32-cam because gives up error of command "WiFi.onEvent(WiFiPointConnected, SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED);". SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED is built-in parameter in Arduino IDE. May be I haven't anyfile. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.
Sketch:
#include <WiFi.h> 
const char* ssid = "CarDrone";
const char* password = "08060905";
String network_ssid = "---";
String network_password = "----";
WebServer server(80);

void WiFiPointConnected(WiFiEvent_t event, WiFiEventInfo_t info) {
  Serial.println("Connected!");
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiPointConnected, SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("ESP32-CAM IP Address: " + WiFi.localIP());
}
void loop() {}

Error:
WiFi.onEvent(WiFiPointConnected, SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED);
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                    WIFI_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED

exit status 1

Compilation error: 'SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'WIFI_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED'?


it says did you mean 'WIFI_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED'?.

I tryed and this. But gives another error:

Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'WiFiClass::onEvent(void (&)(arduino_event_id_t, arduino_event_info_t), wifi_event_t)'

it should be ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_STACONNECTED

your code was for esp32 Arduino version 1. now you use version 3

Yes, it's working, thanks.

Your code is for esp32 Arduino platform version 1, but you compile it with version 3.
In version 2 WiFi.onEvent was changed to use an enum where the name for the new STA connected to SoftAP is ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_STACONNECTED.
The WIFI_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED constant recommended by the compiler is from the IDF framework on which the Arduino platform is built and it is not compatible with Arduino WiFi library's WiFi.onEvent` function.
